Assessing the Convexity of an Optimization Problem
I am trying to analyze the following optimization problem
Objective Function:
The objective is to maximize the total yield (alloc_yield) obtained from allocating assets to different pools.
$$\text{Maximize: } \sum_{i} \text{allocation}_i \times \text{interest_rate}_i$$
Decision Variables:
Let $(allocation_i)$ represent the allocation of assets to pool (i).
Constraints:

Total Asset Constraint: The total allocation should not exceed the total available assets.
$$\sum_{i} allocation_i \leq \text{total_assets}$$

Individual Pool Allocation Constraint: The allocation to each pool should be greater than or equal to the borrowed amount of that pool.
$$allocation_i \geq \text{borrow_amount}_i \quad \forall i$$


I cannot figure out if this problem can be solved using convex optimizers given the non-linear objective function and constraints. Any input is highly appreciated!
Edit: I forgot the interest rate calculations. Appending them below
Interest Rate Calculation:
$$
\text{interest_rate}_i = \begin{cases} 
\text{pool}_i["base\_rate"] + \left(\frac{\text{util_rate}_i}{\text{pool}_i["optimal\_util\_rate"]}\right) \times \text{pool}_i["base\_slope"] & \text{if } \text{util_rate}_i < \text{pool}_i["optimal\_util\_rate"] \\
\text{pool}_i["base\_rate"] + \text{pool}_i["base\_slope"] + \left(\frac{\text{util_rate}_i - \text{pool}_i["optimal\_util\_rate"]}{1 - \text{pool}_i["optimal\_util\_rate"]}\right) \times \text{pool}_i["kink\_slope"] & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Utility Rate Calculation:
$$
\text{util_rate}_i = \frac{\text{pool}_i["borrow\_amount"]}{\text{allocation}_i}
$$
Given these calculations, the objective function is no more linear. Can we still find the global maxima while optimizing this problem? Which algorithm will be suitable for solving this problem?

We have to distinguish between parameters and decision variables.
Parameters are given to us, in this context, interest rates, total assets and borrow amount.
The decision variable is the allocation amount.
For your objective function and constraint, we can see that it is just linear combination of the decision variables, hence they are linear.
This is a linear programming problem which is convex.

Response to the updated question: The updated objective function seems nonlinear though I have not proved it, since the interest rate is also a variable and the interest rate is a nonlinear function of allocation.
In this case, we might want to use strategy such as basin hopping.

Updated the question. Please have a look
